# How would I make this credit card validator /identifier output to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, credit-card

I'm working on a project for credit card identification and validation, I'm trying to use nodes fs to write to another file and my goal to do that is use an array, fill with each line that this function outputs. Here is my full code block:

```
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { createInterface } from 'readline'
import { getCompanyName } from './cardType'
import cardValidator from './cardValidator'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const lineReader = createInterface({
input: createReadStream('data/input.txt')
})

const output: string[] = []

lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
var company = `${getCompanyName(creditCard)}: ${creditCard} (${
cardValidator(creditCard) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
})`

//make company output an array called results then use results to 
//wright lines to the output file  

fs.writeFile('./data/output.txt', results[0, 1, 2, 3, etc], err => {
if (err) throw err && console.log('it broke as heck')
console.log('The file has been saved!')
})
})
```

How would I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code block now It is done and working:

```
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { createInterface } from 'readline'
import { getCompanyName } from './cardType'
import cardValidator from './cardValidator'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const lineReader = createInterface({
input: createReadStream('data/input.txt')
})

const output: string[] = []

lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
output.push(
`${getCompanyName(creditCard)}: ${creditCard} (${
  cardValidator(creditCard) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
})`
)
})

lineReader.on('close', () => {
fs.writeFile('./data/output.txt', output.join('\n'), err => {
if (err) throw err
console.log('The file has been saved!')
})
})
```

I added in the event processing the cards into `output.push` then created a new `lineReader` function writing the processed cards into `output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get a `done` event, something like a simple callback would work:

```
const read = (cb: (lines: string) => void) => { // Wrap in a new function 
  const lineReader = createInterface({
    input: createReadStream('data/input.txt')
  })

  const output: string[] = []

  lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
    output.push(creditCard);
  });

  lineReader.on('done', (creditCard: string) => {
    cb(output)
  });
}
```

This is similar to how you would use `setTimeout` etc.

Comment: This doesn't work unless It's because I don't understand what you mean by the done event, I googled it and couldn't find anything on it - what is it?